# VMWare Player disable screen timeout

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I want to setup VMWare Player such that the screen of my virtual machine will never go black from inactivity again.

Can I achieve that?

---

Note: my virtual machine is a text-interface Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe VMWare Player blanks the screen after inactivity. It is is likely Ubuntu's built-in "Screensaver" functionality.

Check and see if this works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server